# Providing feedback to the user when an entry that is added is the same as a current entry

Tags: iphone, time

[image]I'm trying to give the user the ability to add alarm times for a reminder.

In this view, you can see that I have 1:19am twice.  What happens is if you press the plus button, then I add a row based on what's in the bottom picker display.  I originally had it so that if you press + and the time already exists, a row is not added.  I didn't want to pop up an alert saying that they needed to select a time that doesn't exist already.

Similarly, when the user selects a row and the row is highlighted, you can move the picker to change the time and they can change the time to a time that already exists in the table.

When they leave the screen, I'd like to only have one alarm per time.  Do I show the user an alert if two times are the same?  Or do I simply delete any duplicate entries from the table when they leave the screen and when they come back they'll see that the app took care of duplicates for them.  Or is there something else that is pretty standard that I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simpler answer... ignore duplicates. There is no reason for them. When a duplicate would be added, just have nothing at all happen (the duplicate is immediately and silently removed). Duplicate times serve no function at all, so the user will have no confusion when they don't appear. If you can within your programming framework, you should highlight the item that was already there, so the user doesn't feel ignored.